# In Outlook email code, must align tables left so they align in TD, but want them centered on mobile. Cannot use media queries or style sheets

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to force a TD to center all content on mobile within in without using style sheets? In Outlook I have 3 tables, all aligned left so that they line up horizontally on desktop. On mobile when the tables all drop below each other, they are still aligned left so not centered on the device. Even though the housing TD is align="center", the table's align="left" overrides. I'm wracking my brain and nothing seems to work. And I cannot use @media queries in Outlook, so it has to be all inline styles, simplicity within html. Can anyone give me any ideas? This is a riddle I can't crack. HTML is here, thanks all!!!

Here is the html that gets loaded into Outlook-

https://comms.pmail4.com/PoliteMail2/files/MSFT_001_3column.html

Comment: welcome! check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Nest 2 tables. If you are formatting emails this is a major headache. The gist for you would be to create a `table` that spans the full width with a row of 3 `td`s spread evenly. Make each `td` have content center aligned. Make a `table` inside each `td` which contains only your desired `td`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I can have a row that spans the full with with 3 tds spread evenly. This would keep all the tables within that row on mobile and break the responsiveness, and not allow the tables to drop down on each other, but all will stay within that row.